# Who administers the lashes against one who transgressed a Torah law or Rabbinic mandate?

Tags: halacha, lashes-malkos

Is the one administering the lashes the same person? Are there shifts? Is it an exceptionally righteous person? It would appear to me that one chosen to administer lashes might experience haughtiness.

Comment: Is there ever lashing without witnesses?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_The_Sanhedrin_and_the_Penalties_within_their_Jurisdiction.16.9

Comment: In short, someone (or several people) is appointed by the court to do that job.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Nathan and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!